# Recursive calls from a catch block

Tags: c#, try-catch

I'm coding a method where an attempt to upload a document is wrapped within a Try/Catch block.

If the attempt fails, I'm incrementing the Retry counter and recursively calling the same method.

I'm not clear on the execution path in those cases where the 'Catch' block is hit. Initial tests show that the 'return null' statement is executed after that first recursive call executes. Perhaps the 'return null' statement needs to be within the Catch block but outside the retries<3 loop?

```
public RssUploadDocOutput UploadInvoice(string filename, int retries)
        {
            var returnsOutput = new RssUploadDocOutput();

            GoogleSheetsCommand sscmd = new GoogleSheetsCommand("UploadDocument", ConnSheets);
            sscmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sscmd.Parameters.Add(new GoogleSheetsParameter("LocalFile", filename));

            //int retries = 0; removed 

            try
            {
             GoogleSheetsDataReader rdr = sscmd.ExecuteReader();
               rdr.Read();

                returnsOutput.ID = rdr[0].ToString();
                [...]
                returnsOutput.Weblink = rdr[6].ToString();

                return returnsOutput;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //retries++;
                Logger.Instance.LogException(ex);
                if (retries < 3)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000 * retries);
                    UploadInvoice(filename, retries+1);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: You are resetting that 'retries' counter with every call, maybe supply as an extra argument?

Comment: the variable retries is declared inside the method (`int retries = 0;`) . Try to move that out side.

Comment: The `retries` variable is declared within the method. It won't ever be >= 3.

Comment: The 'UploadInvoice' recursive call returns a value -> return that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needs two changes:

1. Declare the variable retries outside of the function
2. Return the value returned by the UploadInvoice method (in the catch block)

   ```
   if (retries < 3)
   {
       Thread.Sleep(1000 * retries);
       return UploadInvoice(filename);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the variable outside your method. Otherwise everytime, it will reset to 0 and you will end up in never ending.....

```
int retries = 0;
public RssUploadDocOutput UploadInvoice(string filename)
{
  //no need of int retries = 0; inside the method 

  //do stuff
}
```

your catch block will return `null` only if it failed all 3 times.

*EDIT* :  You are **SILENTLY KILLING** the exception. Are you sure you want to do that ?. You may probably want to Log it or Notify back to the caller.

Comment: Note, this requires manually resetting the counter before you do the next upload (else it will only ever try three times on the first upload).  And putting the counter outside of the method kills thread safety, in case you care about that.  You'll need some kind of synchronization if you want it back.